# How to create a keynote theme?

Tags: keynote

How do I create a theme for keynote? I know how to install a theme, and I want to create my own theme. I can create the images my self. Is there any app or anything to do so?

Comment: First Google link: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/09/25/how-to-create-keynote-themes/

Comment: @Mateusz That's a bit outdated

Comment: @GeorgeGarside You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Keynote 6 then all you have to do is take an existing theme, make the modifications that you want then choose **Save Theme** from the file menu

[image: Keynote File Menu]

It well then ask what you want to do with your shiny new theme

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but will it override the existing theme?

Comment: I have added extra information to the answer. It will either add a new theme to the chooser or you can save it as a file on your local machine. Neither should overwrite the existing theme

Answer (score 3):

I did this myself but I noticed there was a step missing. If you want to create a new background with an image you import, make sure you pull down the divider on the sidebar and add the image to the MASTER slide. Then you can save the theme. I tried saving the theme before doing this and couldn't figure out why it still looked like the old theme when I opened the new one.

Comment: This is critical. Essentially the changes you make on the slides only apply to the specific slide, unless you update the master slides.